# How can I get a child route to open beside its parent counterpart?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have this route that path `/customers` should handle children.

```
{ 
    path: '/customers/...', 
    name: 'CustomerList', 
    component: CustomersComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
}
```

CustomersComponent

```
@Component({
    template: `
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
       </div>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/',    component: CustomerListComponent,   name: 'CustomerList', useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/:id', component: CustomerDetailComponent, name: 'CustomerDetail' }
])
export class CustomersComponent {
}
```

How can I map my routes so that I can have my list on the left side and selecting an item will open it on the right while changing the URL from `/customers` to `/customers/1`?

What is currently happening is that selecting a customer opens in a whole new page. I'm assuming this is caused by my `CustomersComponent` only having 1 `router-outlet`, which can either be `CustomerListComponent` or `CustomerDetailComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer at this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/mWckPyTw2c8JFlF6uUlK/) from CaptainCodeman originally posted [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6204#issuecomment-173387844).

Lots of additional information in this [Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6204) issue.